# Razor checkbox not binding to Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox

I'm an asp.net mvc newbie. I have a checkbox in my form

```
@Html.CheckBox("Don't show my number", Model.IsPhonePublic)
```

But whether I check the box or not the `Model.IsPhonePublic` is always false while submitting the form. Any pointers

Comment: @Html.CheckBox(Model.IsPhonePublic), then a separate label

Comment: Shouldn't the label be "Show my number"? or are you always using the oposite of the boolean value? :-)

Comment: I recently discovered that if you have another reference to the same model property, such as a @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.IsPhonePublic)  in the same form that you have @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsPhonePublic), then the controller may not receive the expected value. Just something to noodle around if you can't find why the value is wrong when you are sitting at a breakpoint in your controller! Also, I do not know if that applies to core or not.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**You are using the helper wrong**, See definition [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504981(v=vs.118).aspx) :

So you do this:

```
@Html.Label("Don't show my number") 
@Html.CheckBox("IsPhonePublic", Model.IsPhonePublic)
```

or

```
@Html.Label("Don't show my number") 
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsPhonePublic)
```

or third and clean solution:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.IsPhonePublic) 
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsPhonePublic)
```

And in you model definition:

```
[DisplayName("Don't show my number")]
public bool IsPhonePublic { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsPhonePublic)
 @Html.Label('Don't Show my number.')
```