# How to Pass default values as False of checkBox to controller action in asp.net mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to set default value of checkbox as False. if the checkbox is checked then pass true otherwise false to Controller.

This is my View

```html
 <div class="form-group">
  @Html.CheckBox("Stratling", (Model != null && Model.Stratling.HasValue) ? 
      Model.Stratling : true)
   <label>
      Stratling
   </label>
 </div>
```

This code pass true value to controller when checkbox is not checked.
i want it as false value.

Can anyone guide me in right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't do that. HTML Form does not submit anything if a checkbox is not checked. So if you receive nothing, you can assume it's false.

Comment: @LukeVo MVC helpers add a hidden input so that unchecked values are also submitted.

Comment: `This code pass true value to controller when checkbox is not checked` that shouldn't happen. why are you jumping though so many hoops to set the checkbox, `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Stratling)` should just work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Razor checkbox not binding to Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24446828/razor-checkbox-not-binding-to-model)

Comment: @Liam So how to set the value at the edit time?

Comment: Did you set public bool? Stratling { get; set; } in your model?

Comment: It just happens. When the form is submitted the server side interprets the binding back into the model. You don't need to do anything, essentially ticking the tickbox sets `Stratling` to `true` and unticking it sets it to `false` (**after the form is submitted**). I don't really see any point in making `Stratling` `Nullable<>`, the form can't send a null

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Html.CheckBoxFor` method, what it renders out is:

When the checkbox is not checked, it returns False.  When the checkbox is checked, it returns True,False and the internal framework parses it to true.  You could use the same approach by adding a hidden field with a False value, and handle appropriately.